# Hiding an element in internet explorer leaves artifacts on the screen (IE 10-11)

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

We use custom selectbox elements for our page (for reasons), but in one specific place and only with IE (in my case version 10 and 11), there is a problem.

When you open the box and close it, sometimes the browser leaves visual artifacts of that element. If there is a button below the element (in the opened state), then those artifacts are still on top of that button UNTIL you hover over the button, then those artifacts disappear at that place.

I think everyone experienced this behaviour at some point in his life with windows or something else. Sorry if my description isn't perfect.

Here are some screenshots (The red boxes are censored text, sorry):

Open state:
[image]

Closed state with artifacts:
[image]

Hope my description is accurate, I desperately need a fix for this.

I can't reproduce it on my system, but our QA guy can reproduce it consistently. It also changes depending on the size of the browser. On some sizes it doesn't seem to happen at all. It must be some weird rendering glitch of IE.

I don't think it has anything to do with our custom selectbox element, because it happens only in this specific place and in our old design we experienced it in a different place with a completely different element. At that time I thought it's because the DOM is too complicated for IE, but this page has almost no elements.

EDIT: I Just found out that if I minimize the window and maximize it again, the artifacts disappear, which should confirm that this is a rendering glitch, right?

EDIT 2: Here is the code and css of our custom selectbox

HTML:

```
<div class="input_selectbox">
        <label>Title</label>

    <div class="input_selectbox__head" data-placeholder="">
            <label>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5-10909">
                 Dummy 1
            </label>
    </div>

    <div class="input_selectbox__body">
            <label data-value="" class="">

                No Option
            </label>
            <label id="5-10909" data-value="5-10909" class="input_selectbox__option--selected" data-default="true">

                Dummy 1
            </label>
            <label id="5-12568" data-value="5-12568" class="">

                Dummy 2
            </label>
            <label id="5-20001" data-value="5-20001" class="">

                Dummy 3
            </label>
            <label id="5-20002" data-value="5-20002" class="">

                Dummy 4
            </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

LESS:

```
.input_combobox, .input_selectbox {
    display: block;
    font-family: RobotoCondensed-Regular;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    label {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

.input_selectbox {
    font-family: Roboto-Regular;
}

.input_selectbox__head {
    border: 1px solid @colorBorderGrey;
    transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.3s;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: flex;
    background-color: @colorLightestGrey;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: space-between;

    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        border-color: @colorDarkGrey;

        &:after {
            color: @colorBlue;
        }
    }

    label {
        display: flex;
        user-select: none;
        pointer-events: none;

        i {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
    }

    &:after {
        content: "\f078";
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-rendering: auto;
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
        font-weight: 900;
        pointer-events: none;
        transition: color 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, background-color 0.2s;
        display: block;
        padding-left: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

.input_combobox--active, .input_selectbox--active {
    .input_combobox__head, .input_selectbox__head {
        background-color: @colorLightGrey;

        &:hover {
            border: 1px solid @colorBorderGrey;

            &:after {
                color: @colorDarkGrey;
            }
        }

        &:after {
            background-color: @colorLightGrey;
        }

        span {
            background-color: @colorGreyHover;
        }
    }
}

.input_combobox__body, .input_selectbox__body {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.05) 0px 2px 5px 0px;
    background-color: @colorWhite;
    border: 1px solid @colorBorderGrey;
    border-top: none;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 499;

    label {
        font-family: RobotoCondensed-Regular;
        font-size: 16px;
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.3s;
        border-bottom: 1px solid @colorBorderGrey;

        &:hover {
            background-color: @colorLightGrey;
        }

        &:last-child {
            border-bottom: none;
        }

        i {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        input[type=checkbox] {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}

.input_combobox__body--top, .input_selectbox__body--top {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px -2px 5px 0px;
}

.input_combobox__option--inactive, .input_selectbox__option--inactive {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function selectbox()
{
    // click
    $(document).on("click", ".input_selectbox__head", function ()
    {
        $(this).trigger("selectbox:toggle");
    });

    // toggle
    $(document).on("selectbox:toggle", ".input_selectbox__head", function ()
    {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass("input_selectbox--active")) 
        {
            $(this).trigger("selectbox:close");
        }
        else 
        {
            $(this).trigger("selectbox:open");
        }
    });

    // open
    $(document).on("selectbox:open", ".input_selectbox__head", function ()
    {
        var selectbox = $(this).closest(".input_selectbox");

        if (!selectbox.hasClass("readonly") && !selectbox.hasClass("input--disabled"))
        {
            $(".input_selectbox--active .input_selectbox__head").trigger("selectbox:close");

            // Positionierung
            var header = selectbox.find(".input_selectbox__head");
            var headerHeight = header.outerHeight();
            var selectboxBody = selectbox.find(".input_selectbox__body");
            var headerPositionX = header.offset().left;
            var headerPositionY = header.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
            var bodyPositionY = headerPositionY + headerHeight;

            selectboxBody.removeClass("input_selectbox__body--top");

            selectboxBody.css({
                "top": bodyPositionY,
                "left": headerPositionX,
                "width": selectbox.width(),
                "bottom": ""
            });

            selectbox.addClass("input_selectbox--active");
            selectboxBody.show();

            // check if offscreen
            var isOut = isOutOfViewport(selectboxBody.get(0));

            if (isOut.bottom)
            {
                selectboxBody.addClass("input_selectbox__body--top");

                selectboxBody.css({
                    top: "",
                    bottom: ($(window).innerHeight() - headerPositionY - 1)
                });
            }

            // close combobox on parent scroll
            var scrollParent = getScrollParent(header[0]);

            $(scrollParent).one("scroll", function ()
            {
                header.trigger("selectbox:close");
            });

            $(document).one("scroll", function ()
            {
                header.trigger("selectbox:close");
            });

            $(window).one("resize", function ()
            {
                header.trigger("selectbox:close");
            });
        }
    });

    // close
    $(document).on("selectbox:close", ".input_selectbox__head", function ()
    {
        var selectbox = $(this).closest(".input_selectbox");

        selectbox.removeClass("input_selectbox--active");
        var selectboxBody = selectbox.find(".input_selectbox__body");

        selectboxBody.hide();
    });

    // change option
    $(document).on("click", ".input_selectbox__body > label", function ()
    {
        var label = $(this);
        var value = label.attr("data-value");
        var headerLabel = $(this).closest(".input_selectbox__body").siblings(".input_selectbox__head").children("label");
        var name = headerLabel.find("input[type=hidden]").attr("name");

        label.addClass("input_selectbox__option--selected").siblings().removeClass("input_selectbox__option--selected");

        headerLabel.html(label.html());
        headerLabel.append('<input type="hidden" name="' + name + '" value="' + value + '" />');
        headerLabel.closest(".input_selectbox__head").trigger("selectbox:close");

        $(this).closest(".input_selectbox").trigger("selectbox:change").trigger("change");
    });

    // close selectbox on outside click
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $(document).on("click touchstart", function (event)
        {
            if ($(event.target).closest('.input_selectbox--active').length == 0)
            {
                $(".input_selectbox--active .input_selectbox__head").trigger("selectbox:close");
            }
        });
    });

    // form reset
    $(document).on("reset", "form", function ()
    {
        var selectboxes = $(this).find(".input_selectbox");

        selectboxes.each(function ()
        {
            $(this).find(".input_selectbox__body").find("label[data-default=true]").click();
        });
    });   
}
```

Comment: With only description of the issue, we cannot confirm that whether it is any IE bug or it is the issue related with your custom control. It is better if you post any sample code or detailed steps to test the issue. Than it can be helpful to make any decision. Even if it is an IE bug than also it will not going to fix as IE will not going to receive any feature related update. In that case it will be better to use MS Edge browser.

Comment: Of course if it's an IE bug it won't be fixed, but there is probably a workaround for it if we would know what causes it (we must support IE10+). I will post some code tomorrow when I'm at the office again. You're right, while I don't expect that to be the problem (although what else could be?), there is no reason not to post some code.

Comment: I try to refer your edit section in the original post and from that description it looks like it can be a rendering issue or any kind of glitch. If possible for you than please try to provide a sample code for it. We will try to test the issue with IE 11 to produce the issue and find any possible solution or workaround for it. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I edited the post with the entire code for the custom selectbox. Hope that helps figuring this out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I try to test your above above posted code but when I run it. I found that it is not creating any drop down. Also there is no any error in the console. I try to check it in various browsers and got the same results. See here: https://i.postimg.cc/bwSq5Ssn/239.png Can you please check that code and verify that whether it is able to produce the drop down or not?

Comment: The code definitly works. The problem may be, that you interpreted the "CSS" part as "CSS", but actually it's an uncompiled "LESS". I should compile the Less and post that instead of the Less, will do that tomorrow when I am at the office again. Sorry. You could check if the script is at least working by checking if the classes get appended correctly etc., but without the proper css it will obviously not work correctly. Also I can guarantuee you that you won't be able to reproduce it anyway, because it only happens in that specific instance and I cant reproduce it myself even, only our QA guy.

Comment: I tried to convert your LESS code to CSS and again try to produce the issue. Still your drop down is not working. See here: https://i.postimg.cc/pLBbqThQ/73.gif You can also check the code and try to verify it.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Sorry I don't know what to say. I don't want to waste your time. I checked the HTML, LESS and Javascript multiple times and can't see why it wouldn't work. I'm currently not at the office. Next time I will try all of this in a vacuum to check if there is anything wrong with the code. Thank you for your time!!